# Workflow for Beta Testing with Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I have built an app with Phonegap Build, and I have entered the signin keys for iOS and Android. What is then the workflow to send the app to beta testers ?

Should I just ask them for their UDID (for iOS) and then send them the QRcode from PG Build ? 
Or should I upload the PG Build app file to the respective developper center (iOs or Android) and then send it to the beta testers ?

Thanks